# When I'm creating Flutter new project lib folder is missing in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, new-operator, lib

[image]

When I am creating a new Flutter project in Android Studio, lib folder is missing. How to fix it?

I run `Flutter doctor`,  everything is fine but I am facing this problem.

Comment: You are opeaning a Android directory of Flutter project. Try to open project from flutter project level.

Answer (score 7):

As "Devarsh Ranpara" comment 
change Android directory to Project

[image: change to Project]

Answer (score 5):

Just delete .idea folder from project directory an re run android studio. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hi

You should choose this option!!

Comment: Your answer could've been more informative by saying where you can find the option or how can he prevent this from happening again